# Thumbnail component issue in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, components, webpack-style-loader

I have added the thumbnail component into my project. I got to see the following error in my project after adding it. The error is shown in the following image.
[image]

Here's my webpack.config.js file code which might help you on understanding the issue. There's a loader to be specified there. I don't know what's the specified loader for this. Anyone faced the same issue?

Any help?

```
**/*webpack.config.js*/**

/* eslint comma-dangle: ["error",


{"functions": "never", "arrays": "only-multiline", "objects":
 "only-multiline"} ] */

const webpack = require('webpack');
const pathLib = require('path');

const devBuild = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const config = {
  entry: [
    'es5-shim/es5-shim',
    'es5-shim/es5-sham',
    'babel-polyfill',
    './app/bundles/HelloWorld/startup/registration',
  ],

  output: {
    filename: 'webpack-bundle.js',
    path: pathLib.resolve(__dirname, '../app/assets/webpack'),
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({ NODE_ENV: 'development' }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: require.resolve('react'),
        use: {
          loader: 'imports-loader',
          options: {
            shim: 'es5-shim/es5-shim',
            sham: 'es5-shim/es5-sham',
          }
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,  
        include: /node_modules/,  
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = config;

if (devBuild) {
  console.log('Webpack dev build for Rails'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  module.exports.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
} else {
  console.log('Webpack production build for Rails'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
}
```

And Here's the code where I called the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Thumbnail from 'react-native-thumbnail-video';

class VideoThumnail extends Component {
   render() {
     return(
       <div>
         <Thumbnail url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgj3D5-jJ74" />
       </div>
     );
   }
}

export default VideoThumnail;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a rule only for jsx. Try to add `js` extension in webpack also

```
 {
   test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
   use: 'babel-loader',
   exclude: /node_modules/,
 }
```

Also i see es6 synax, so try to add .babelrc in project root with this

```
{
  "presets": ["stage-0"]
}
```

and install `babel-preset-env` (npm install --save babel-preset-env)

Comment: i also see that error in node_modules, but you have exclude it. So try to remove this line also `exclude: /node_modules/`

Comment: okk.. after adding this thing it's showing this now - **Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[3] has an unknown property 'presets'. These properties are valid:
   object { enforce?, exclude?, include?, issuer?, loader?, loaders?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, query?, resource?, resourceQuery?, compiler?, rules?, test?, use? }**

Comment: you should add `presets` in .babelrc file. Please create it and put that code there

Comment: in the .babelrc file I'm already having **{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2", "react"]
}**

Comment: than try to change "stage-2" to "stage-0"

Comment: yes, I changed. Now it's showing this - **Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "stage-0" relative to directory "/home/subhojit/rails-application/client"
    at /home/subhojit/rails-application/client/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293:19**

Comment: install babel-preset-env (npm install --save babel-preset-env)

Comment: And remove  exclude: /node_modules/, in webpack config. This should work

Comment: Tried this just now man. It's not working. Now, I'm getting whole bunch of component errors.